# Angular show fixed components when nesting components

Tags: angular

I am nesting admin module in the main app module in my project

Inside the admin module I have 2 components register - login and the admin module has its own routing module

Now I need to make a navbar for the admins and put it above the `<router-outlet></router-outlet>`

When I created navbar component and put `<app-navbar></app-navbar>` in the admin component

I got this error `error NG8001: 'app-navbar' is not a known element`

This is my project structure

[image: Project structure]

Admin module

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

import { AdminRoutingModule } from './admin-routing.module';

import { RegisterComponent } from './register/register.component';
import { LoginComponent } from './login/login.component';
import { ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { NavbarComponent } from './navbar/navbar.component';


@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        RegisterComponent,
        LoginComponent,
        NavbarComponent
    ],
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        AdminRoutingModule,
        ReactiveFormsModule,
        HttpClientModule
    ]
})
export class AdminModule { }
```

Main App module

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AdminComponent } from './admin/admin.component';

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        AdminComponent
    ],
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        AppRoutingModule,
        HttpClientModule
    ],
    providers: [],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

I am nesting the two modules with lazy-loading routing so for fixing this error I must move the navbar component to the main app module but I need it to be in the right structure

How can I fix this error please?

Answer (score 0):

I have two solution for this -

**Solution 1 -**

Provide NavbarComponent into AdminComponent

```
@Component({
   selector: 'app-admin',
   templateUrl: './admin.component.html',
   styleUrls: ['./admin.component.scss'],
   providers: [NavbarComponent]
})
```

**Solution 2 -**

You can also export NavbarComponent in your module, then you don't need to provide it in AdminComponent.

```
@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        //Declare Component
    ],
    imports: [
       //Import Modules
    ],
    exports: [
       NavbarComponent
    ],
})
export class YourModule { }
```